# saveInBackground is not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

```
NSLog(@"pressed");
    [_order setObject:_placeChosen forKey:@"place"];
    _order[@"place"] = _placeChosen;
    //[_order saveEventually];
    [_order saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"saving...");
        if(succeeded){
            NSLog(@"succeeded dude");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pickDate" sender:self];        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"error");
            NSLog([error debugDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

That's my code. As you can see, I've logged all the possible places and here is the crazy thing: There is no error! The "error" won't show up nor will the debugDescription. "saving..." is not showing up either. however, "pressed" DOES show up. I thought it was faulty network connection but i waited for a while, tried a bunch of times, went to different places and it STILL doesn't work. Is this a bug? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Can you post more code for context? What is the type of _order?

Comment: _order is a PFObject and _placeChosen is a NSString

Comment: It seems that the block ok saveInBackgroundWithBlock is not invoked.  Can you check the inside of the saveInBackgroundWithBlock?

Comment: what do you mean by "check the inside"

Comment: where is _order instantiated? Are you sure it is not nil?

Comment: Are you blocking the main thread somewhere? That can explain why the completion block is blocked from running.

Comment: You're double setting the key "place" and definitely need to log out the contents of _order to ensure it's actually a parse object.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my prepareForSegue in the previous controller, I had spelled the name of the segue identifier wrong so that the _order wasn't being transferred over thus it was nil. Fixing the spelling fixed the issue. Although, Parse should really give an error saying that the PFObject is nil so it can't be saved.